# Command \c@subfigure already defined

Tags: subcaption

when I try `\usepackage{subcaption}` immediately at the beginning of my document I get an error:

`Command \c@subfigure already defined`

What can I do?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I guess we need [more information](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Which class are you using? Which packages do you load?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that two packages define this counter. Ensure that you only load the required packages. Here, with `subcaption` load `caption` before, but not `subfigure` or `subfig`, which do a similar job but are not required if you already use `subcaption`, as mentioned.

Already loading `subfig` and then `subfigure` produces this error. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

To sum up: just load the needed package(s), and remove unnecessary packages.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but first I had to do a `Clean All` before I called Latex